# Ext JS 4.2 CSS variable for specific container in custom theme

Tags: extjs4, sass, extjs4.2

Some Ext JS container exposes CSS variables without any mixin.  For example, `fieldcontainer`.  In my custom theme I want to style two `fieldcontainer`s differently using the available CSS variables for `fieldcontainer`.

I know it can be done by applying CSS.  Is there a way to achieve it by setting the CSS variables?

For example,

```
    .my-class-one {
        $form-label-font-color: #FFFFFF
    }

    .my-class-two {
        $form-label-font-color: #000000
    }
```

Is it possible? If possible, where do I put this code?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

Define a style in the sass/src/ folder:

```
.my-class-one .x-form-item-label{
    color: $my-class-one-label-color;
}

.my-class-two .x-form-item-label{
    color: $my-class-two-label-color;
}
```

...and initialize the variables in the sass/var/ like this:

```
$my-class-one-label-color: #FFFFFF;
$my-class-two-label-color: #000000;
```

You should put your scss variables in the sass/var/ folder and your styles in the sass/src/ folder.. And in these two folders keep the same structure as in your app folder. so if you write a style for your view in app/view/Home.js so place your style in the sass/src/view/Home.scss file.

Useful link: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/theming

Comment: With this approach I will have to style the component from scratch.  I want to extend from an existing theme e.g. `neptune` and just vary one variable e.g. `font` leaving other inherited from `neptune`.

Comment: No you dont. define a standard form (panel) or whatever. define a cls like my-class-one in the config. You will see that it has the standard neptune style. With these two styles i wrote above you will only overwrite the color of all elements with the class x-form-item-label in an element with the class my-class-one e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Above approach should work though i personally avoid adding style to internal class names.

Another approach could be defining a new UI for your container.

Have a look at: 
[Creating Custom Component UIs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/theming) section in theming guide.

Comment: Personally I prefer to avoid those internal class names as well.  Things may not work in the future version if those internal class name changes.  The document only shows how to create custom theme where there is a `CSS Mixin`.  Any pointer to how to create `CSS Mixin` for `fieldcontainer` where no CSS Mixin is provided?